# JS после нажатие на кнопку спарсить значение из div в поле input type=text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Интересует как можно сделать парсинг значение из блока div в input или что то подобное
То есть, имеется значение в ABC, после нажатия на кнопку button -> значение ABC - должно перейти в поле input type=text id="parsfield"

```html
<div id="result-btn">ABC</div>

<button class="btn">pars</button>

<input type="text" id="parsval" value="">
```

Как можно реализовать данный функционал ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('input').value = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML;
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div id="result-btn">ABC</div>

<button class="btn">pars</button>

<input type="text" id="parsval" value="">
```